# Kivy - Unable to open device "/dev/input/event7" on Ubuntu, no permission

Tags: python, kivy, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and every time I run any Kivy App (I'm new to both Ubuntu and Kivy), I get the message:

```
[WARNING] [MTD] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event7". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
```

It works normally, I would just like to know why the message appears and if I can get rid of it. It doesn't matter if I run the app from PyCharm or Terminal. When I run it in Windows, everything is fine without this message.

Answer (score 3):

This message appears because Kivy queries each input device to see if it should listen to it. It doesn't matter that it failed to access this one, it's normal.

It's a minor bug that this message is printed each time, since it isn't really necessary, but nobody has ever got around to fixing it.